# TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined using Discordjs v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I'm working on a JavaScript Discord(v12.4.0) bot and I'm trying to create a channelinfo command but I have an error when defining and finding the propierties of message.channel.

This is the **channelinfo.js**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: "channelinfo",
  cooldown: 5,
  aliases: ["ci", "infochannel"],
  description: "Displays info about a channel!",
  guildOnly: true,
  execute(client, message, args) {
  
  const Discord = require("discord.js")

//Definimos discord.

// const channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.id == args[0])

//Definimos el canal del cual sacaremos informacion. Obteniendo el primer canal mencionado o la primera id.
    
//if (!channel) return message.reply("You must enter a channel!")
//Si  no menciono un canal o no puso una id, retorna.


//Definimos el embed que enviaremos
 const cha = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    
   .addField(`Name:`, `- ${Discord.Util.escapeMarkdown(message.channel.name)}`)

//Obtenemos el nombre del canal.

    .addField(`Mention:`, `- \`${message.channel}\``)

//Un simple ejemplo de como se menciona este.

    .addField(`ID:`, `- ${message.channel.id}`)

//Se obtiene la id del canal.

    .addField(`Type`, `- ${message.channel.type}`)

//Obtenemos el tipo de canal, noticias, texto, voz etc
    
     .addField(`Is it nsfw?`, `${message.channel.nsfw}`)

//Revisamos si el canal es nswf, mediante un boolean (false | true)

    .addField(`Topic:`, `- ${message.channel.topic.toString().length < 1 ? "There's no topic" : message.channel.topic}`)

//Se obtiene el tema del canal, si el contenido es menor a 1 caracter (Se hace esto por que a veces se buguean los temas) retorne a "No hay un tema."
//Si hay un tema, lo envia.
   
    .addField(`Category:`, `- ${message.channel.parent.name}`)
 
//Obtenemos la categoria en el que esta el canal.
    
    .setColor("RANDOM") //Color(?
    
    message.channel.send(cha)

}}
```

And this is the **console log error**

```
2020-10-26T13:29:59.413677+00:00 app[worker.1]:     TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
2020-10-26T13:29:59.413677+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.execute (/app/commands/channelinfo.js:26:72)
```

At first, I tryed adding a const that will get the channel with mention or with the ID. The code was this one:

```
const channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]) || message.channel;
```

As it didn't work, I tryed only defining channel as message.channel (const channel = message.channel) but i had the same error.

Then I erased the const line and I used `message.channel` instead of `channel` at the embed files but I still get the same error.

I am sure that it isn't an error caused for the command handler because all the other commands are working fine.

Curiosity: I tryed making a similar command but displaying info about a role and the error was the same(TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined)

Here's the **bot.js**

```
// require fs para el command handler
const fs = require('fs'); 
// require the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

       const { token, prefix, yt_api_key } = require('./config.json');
// create a new Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();


      
fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    let eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
  });
});


client.noprefixcommands = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./noprefixcommands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let props = require(`./noprefixcommands/${file}`);
    let noprefixcommandName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.noprefixcommands.set(noprefixcommandName, props);
  });
});



client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}



client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;
    
    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
    return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
}
    
          if (command.args && !args.length) {
            let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

       if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }
    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;
    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;
        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before using the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }
    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);
    
try {
    command.execute(message, args);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
}
});


client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

I use Github for editing the code and Heroku for hosting.

I started having that issue when I started building the command at Glitch but I returned to Github and the issue was like the Glitch one.

Please someone help
I would be very greateful

Comment: The error means that you have `someObject.users` in your code somewhere and `someObject` is undefined. The relevant line is missing from your question though.

Comment: @ChrisG So I should add the bot.js file

Comment: The error contains the file and line number where it occurs. It doesn't seem to fit the code/script file in your question though.

Comment: @ChrisG yes sorry I modified a little bit the code. Now I added the bot.js and the original channelinfo.js file.

Comment: Are you still getting the exact same error? Because `.users` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry I am stupid... I sended the userinfo code ._. Yes I am getting the same error (channel instead of users)

Comment: Ok, so check the line the error is pointing to. I assume it'll contain `message.channel`. This line assumes that `message` isn't `undefined`, which is what the error says. So the first order of debugging is `console.log(message)` right before that line to check what's actually stored in there.

Comment: Wow. I added `console.log(message)` and `console.log(message.channel` (exactly in that order) and it returned `null` and `undefined`. `2020-10-26T19:11:14.544199+00:00 app[worker.1]: []
2020-10-26T19:11:14.544329+00:00 app[worker.1]: undefined`

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the signature of the function is `execute(client, message, args)` but you're calling it like `command.execute(message, args);`. The name doesn't matter, only the order of parameters is important.

Comment: Thaaanks! I removed the `client` from the  `command.execute(<>)` and now it works. Really thanks man